# Xcode open full window mode

Tags: ios, xcode

When I create new project on Xcode it always open not the full window, but with the right indentation from the screen and the small indentation from the left. It's very annoying. I should every time stretch Xcode to cover full windown.

[image]

How I can get rid of these indentations and always open new Xcode projects stretched in full window? Like this:

[image]

Comment: If you double click on the top bar of the  XCode. It will automatically stretch with full screen.

Comment: interesting @FaysalAhmed, for me it minimumizes the window, not *fill* or *stretch* to full screen. I also think the OP is asking for something different... a *full, yet sizable* window, not what you'd get by clicking on the "green window button". M question with the OP? Considering the variou screen sizes and resolutions out there, how would one technically accomplish such a thing with their macOS app?

Comment: But I don't want everytime to click on the top bar. I want Xcode launch full screen stretched initially without clicking.